# clean install on system with 2 hard drives

Tags: system-installation

I have a laptop with 2 hard drives 1 is an m.2 SSD 250gb and a 1 TB hard drive I would like to know how to configure this system so that my SSD has the os but the 1tb hard drive handles storage thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

In order to setup your PC in the way you described before, you can do a Manual Partition when you are installing ElementaryOS.

Since I don't know the level of experience you (or the person reading this question) have, I'm going to do a very detailed tutorial so it is clear enough almost for everyone.

I recommend you to firstly check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation), basically there's explained how you can manually partition your disk to install a GNU/Linux distribution, in this case Ubuntu.

When you are installing ElemOS, there is a step which is called "Installation Type". It should look like this: [image: Installation type, ElemOS]

Select the **Something else** option.

The installer will take you to a partition table. There you can see all your Storage Devices. There's also a tab below where they are listed.

So, the trick is on the `/home` partition. There is where all your Documents, Photos, etc... are saved. On your HDD create a new partition with the size you prefer, mount it as `/home` and use it as `ext4`. (Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) again if you have any questions).

On your SSD you can create the `swap area`, `/` (root) and `/boot`partitions. If you are not sure how large should each partition be, go back [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) again.

**Be careful**, since the previous post is a little bit old, it does not have info about UEFI.

Further information about UEFI can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI). The really important thing is knowing if your PC works with UEFI or Legacy. If you are not sure you can google it. (Example: Lenovo Ideapad ### UEFI or Legacy?) Usually you can setup it on the BIOS, but that goes off topic.

If you have Legacy, you can create the `/boot` partition as it is shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) and it's done. Now you have your SSD for the OS and the HDD for storage!

If you have UEFI, don't create the `/boot` partition since your PC won't recognize it. Instead create an `EFI system partition`. 200MB sould be more than enough. (I recommend 100MB).

[image: EFI Partition System]

And *voila*, you have finished!

Please let me know if you have any other question or if something wasn't clear enough.